# Colour definition issue with kivymd

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

How do you use the kivymd ThemeManager color definition in kivymd. I did not understand the documentations(https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/themes/color-definitions/) too clearly. I am trying to have my background colour be `colors["Gray"]["300"]` but Kivymd's ThemeManager palette only allows set colours like Gray, Red, Pink etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use available colours with hue amount which you want. For your case it will be like:

```
self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Gray"
self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"#or "Light" if you want light theme
self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "300"
```